# How to Identify a Magento theme

Tags: php, magento

I came across a magento website

> http://www.gidimall.com/

and

> http://www.konga.com/

I really like and I've been trying to figure out which Magento theme its running on. I followed through with some techniques I found online but I didn't seem to get it.

With the following technique, I was able to determine its running on Magento Community Edition 
*http://www.gidimall.com/giftcard/customer* : If you get a 404 Page Not Found error then that means they are NOT running MEE (Magento Enterprise Edition). If you get redirected to a login page that means they ARE most likely running MEE*

identifying its theme is a bit challenging.

Comment: Email site owner duh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can check in console if there is no caching

[image]

if there is caching then you can enable `path hints`

```
log into the magento back-end admin
Go to System -> Configuration in the main menu
Go to Developer on the bottom left under ADVANCED
Switch to the store view on the top left to your current website or store view.
Under the Debug tab of the same Developer config page you will see a new option appear that will allow you to turn on/off template path hints.
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your response. I don't have access to the magento website's admin

Comment: then as suggested you can check theme by console

Comment: then there is no other way beside the above mentions.
contact to your client for provide admin details.

Answer (score 3):

You can get theme name by "view source" and find `skin` which general themes are stored in skin folder, so path would be

`www.yoursitename.com/skin/frontend/default/theme-name/`

and if it's package then it would be

`www.yoursitename.com/skin/frontend/theme-name/default/`