# How to find Magento theme name?

Tags: magento, themes

How to know Magento theme name
like https://educationmalaysia.gov.my

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Identify a Magento theme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32626997/how-to-identify-a-magento-theme)

Answer (score 0):

You can find by navigating to browser inspector (F12). There you search (CTRL+F to search) for something related to magento's paths for example (catalog, skin, forntend etc.)  then try finding where most on the skin css and js files are coming from for example: skin/frontend/COMPANY_NAME/THEME_NAME/. In most cases if the theme is not custom made, you will find it under the company name and the theme name. If you can't find it, you can continue search some comments in the skin files in the theme js, css and etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the site go to http://yoursite.com/admin

`System > Configuration > General > Design > Packages`

`System > Configuration > General > Design > Themes`

Or as already answered:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/32627148/3650708

Comment: I want to know the theme name of other websites?

Comment: Then you need to view page source on e.g. educationmalaysia.gov.my: `view-source:https://educationmalaysia.gov.my/` and search for **skin/frontend/_some-theme-is-written-here_** where some-theme-is-written-here os the theme name. Hope that helps you. Please let me know ;)